# Is it possible to set font-family in a <option>

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to set `font-family` in a `<option>`? I tried `font-family` and it didn't work. Here is the code I have :

```
var fonts = ["Arial", "Helvetica", "Serif", "Cambria"];
for (i = 0; i < fonts.length;i++) {
    var font  = document.createElement("option");
    var fontT = document.createTextNode(fonts[i]);

    document.getElementById ("t-font").appendChild (font);
    font.appendChild (fontT);
    font.style.fontFamily = fonts[i];
}
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ru6gM/))

Is there something wrong with the js or is it not possible to do it at all with html?

Comment: Have you tried writing some HTML manually, to see if it even works?

Comment: Why did it not work? What actually happens, and what do you expect should happen?

Comment: I tried doing it manually... i dont think i can manually style an individual option. i'm making a rich text editor and i want it to display the font choices in the actual font

Comment: It does work, BTW: http://jsfiddle.net/CYyBq/

Comment: thks... i'll just check my code again and tell you if it works

Comment: it doesnt seem to work on your link either what browser are you using?

Comment: That Fiddle doesn't work in Chrome on Windows 7 ...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the applicable specifications prevents you from setting the font-family on an option element, but browser support is spotty.

Comment: hm... if someone can show me a working example it would be extremely helpful

Comment: @officegunner — Tieson T gave you a working example, you just have to use one of the browsers that supports it.

Comment: My copy of Firefox supports it.

Comment: i see... thts .. anyway its not a crucial feature so its ok

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change approach (or HTML tag), because the `select` element is not appropriate for this purpose. Each Browser behaves differently. I would use the `RADIO` buttons. Like so:

```
<div id="choose_font">
</div>
<script>
    var fonts = ["Arial", "Helvetica", "Serif", "Cambria"];
    var container = document.getElementById('choose_font');
    for (i = 0; i < fonts.length;i++) {
        var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
        var label = document.createElement('LABEL');
        input.setAttribute("id","t_"+fonts[i]);
        input.setAttribute("type","radio");
        input.setAttribute("name","t_font");
        label.setAttribute("for","t_"+fonts[i]);
        label.style.fontFamily = fonts[i];
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fonts[i]));
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(label);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
    }
</script>
```

with an appropriate CSS you can make it look like a select.

Comment: i understand what you are thinking but unfortunately i'm making a rich text editor and radio box is just not an applicable solution

Comment: @officegunner you can use appropriate css, and more js, for make it "like" a selectbox. There is no way otherwise.